# Reduce MySQL Query Runtime

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `cr`.`idCustomer`, `rbase`.`id`
FROM `customers` `t`
    JOIN `customersregion` `cr` ON t.idCustomer = cr.idCustomer
                               and cr.isDeleted = 0
    JOIN `calendaritems` `rbase` ON rbase.idAgentsRegion = cr.idRegion
                                and rbase.isDeleted = 0
where (
    (rbase.startDate <= '2020-07-06 00:00:00' and rbase.endDate   >= '2020-07-06 00:00:00') or
    (rbase.startDate <= '2020-07-28 00:00:00' and rbase.endDate   >= '2020-07-28 00:00:00') or
    (rbase.startDate >= '2020-07-06 00:00:00' and rbase.startDate <= '2020-07-28 23:59:59') or
    (rbase.endDate   >= '2020-07-06 00:00:00' and rbase.endDate   <= '2020-07-28 23:59:59')
)
```

- Database: MySQL
- Customers: 132,000 row
- CustomersRegion: 1,754,000 row
- CalendarItems: 3,838,000 row (with conditions reduce to 555,000 row)
- t.idCustomer & cr.idCustomer & cr.isDeleted & rbase.idAgentsRegion & cr.idRegion & rbase.isDeleted are **indexes**

This query runtime is about 100 seconds and i want to reduce the runtime of this query

I can't have limit on rows or have another condition in tables

Can you help me?

Thank you

Explain Query:
[image]

Customers DDL:

```
create table customers
(
    idCustomer           int auto_increment
        primary key,
    CustomerName         varchar(255)                                  not null comment 'نام فروشگاه',
    FirstName            varchar(60)                                   null comment 'نام رابط',
    LastName             varchar(60)                                   null comment 'نام مشتري',
    idUser               int                                           null comment '!#dont show',
    idPayment            int                                           null,
    idCompany            int             default 0                     not null,
    LatitudePoint        decimal(18, 12) default 0.000000000000        null comment 'gpslat',
    LongitudePoint       decimal(18, 12) default 0.000000000000        null comment 'gpslongs',
    LastOrderDate        datetime        default '0000-00-00 00:00:00' null comment 'lastorderdate',
    VisitPeriod          int             default 0                     null comment 'visitperiod',
    LastVisit            datetime        default '0000-00-00 00:00:00' null comment 'LastVisitDate',
    LastNoOrderDate      datetime        default '0000-00-00 00:00:00' null,
    Credit               decimal(20, 4)  default 0.0000                null comment 'credit',
    RemainCredit         decimal(20, 4)  default 0.0000                null comment 'remaincredit',
    Balance              decimal(20, 4)  default 0.0000                null comment '!#dont show',
    RFID                 varchar(60)                                   null comment 'rfid',
    ReturnCheck          tinyint(1)      default 0                     null comment '!#dont show',
    AccountStatus        tinyint(1)      default 0                     null comment 'accountstatus',
    FaxNumber            varchar(20)                                   null,
    LiquidationDate      date            default '0000-00-00'          null comment '!#dont show',
    EldestDue            date            default '0000-00-00'          null comment '!#dont show',
    MaturityDate         date            default '0000-00-00'          null comment '!#dont show',
    PriceKind            int                                           null,
    isDefault            tinyint(1)      default 0                     not null comment '!#dont show',
    TimeStamp            timestamp       default current_timestamp()   not null on update current_timestamp(),
    isDeleted            tinyint(1)      default 0                     not null,
    Address              varchar(255)                                  null,
    PhoneNumber          varchar(60)                                   null,
    MobileNumber         varchar(60)                                   null,
    CustomerErpCode      varchar(60)                                   null comment '!#dont show',
    StoreType            int                                           null,
    country              varchar(255)                                  null,
    state                varchar(255)                                  null,
    City                 varchar(30)                                   null,
    Region               varchar(30)                                   null,
    idUserCreator        int                                           null,
    idBranche            int                                           null,
    idTagsinfo           int                                           null,
    shop_id              int                                           null,
    shop_id_address      int                                           null,
    lastActivityDate     datetime                                      null,
    lastActivityType     tinyint(1)                                    null,
    duplicateOf          int                                           null,
    isConfirmed          tinyint(1)      default 2                     not null comment '0:rejected - 1:confirmed - 2:notChecked',
    Status               tinyint(1)      default 1                     not null,
    createDate           datetime                                      null,
    idProcess            int                                           null comment 'نیازی نیست به اینکه حتما پروسه داشته باشد',
    idUserConfirmer      int                                           null comment 'this is refered to agents table',
    nextDate             datetime                                      null,
    prevDate             datetime                                      null,
    idImage              int                                           null,
    idColor              int                                           null,
    idRate               int                                           null,
    LastImageDate        datetime                                      null,
    LastOrderAgentName   varchar(255)                                  null,
    LastVisitAgentName   varchar(255)                                  null,
    LastNoOrderAgentName varchar(255)                                  null,
    LastImageAgentName   varchar(255)                                  null,
    LastOrderIdAgent     int                                           null,
    LastVisitIdAgent     int                                           null,
    LastNoOrderIdAgent   int                                           null,
    LastImageIdAgent     int                                           null,
    isSaleActive         tinyint(1)      default 1                     null,
    isReturnActive       tinyint(1)      default 1                     null,
    alley                varchar(256)                                  null,
    street               varchar(256)                                  null,
    plaque               varchar(256)                                  null,
    secondAddress        varchar(255)                                  null,
    description          varchar(255)                                  null,
    appType              varchar(50)     default 'iorder'              not null,
    idPipeline           varchar(255)    default '0'                   null,
    constraint shop_id
        unique (shop_id),
    constraint shop_id_address
        unique (shop_id_address),
    constraint ux_customererp
        unique (CustomerErpCode),
    constraint customers_ibfk_1
        foreign key (idBranche) references branches (idBranche)
            on update set null on delete set null,
    constraint customers_ibfk_2
        foreign key (idTagsinfo) references tagsinfo (idTag)
            on update set null on delete set null,
    constraint customers_ibfk_3
        foreign key (idRate) references rates (idRate)
            on update set null on delete set null,
    constraint customers_ibfk_4
        foreign key (idColor) references colors (idColor)
            on update set null on delete set null,
    constraint customers_ibfk_5
        foreign key (idRate) references rates (idRate)
            on update set null on delete set null,
    constraint customers_ibfk_6
        foreign key (idColor) references colors (idColor)
            on update set null on delete set null,
    constraint fk_customer_agents
        foreign key (idUser) references agents (idAgents)
            on update set null on delete set null,
    constraint fk_customer_paymant
        foreign key (idPayment) references payment (idPayment),
    constraint fk_customer_pricelist
        foreign key (PriceKind) references pricelist (idPriceList),
    constraint fk_customer_storeinfo
        foreign key (StoreType) references storesinfo (idStore)
)
    charset = utf8;

create index fk_customer_agents_idx
    on customers (idUser);

create index fk_customer_paymant_idx
    on customers (idPayment);

create index fk_customer_pricelist_idx
    on customers (PriceKind);

create index fk_customer_storeinfo_idx
    on customers (StoreType);

create index idBranche
    on customers (idBranche);

create index idColor
    on customers (idColor);

create index idProcess
    on customers (idProcess);

create index idRate
    on customers (idRate);

create index idTagsinfo
    on customers (idTagsinfo);

create index idx_isdeleted_customername
    on customers (isDeleted, CustomerName);

create index isdeleted_lat_lng
    on customers (isDeleted, LatitudePoint, LongitudePoint);

create index isdeleted_status_isconfirmed
    on customers (isDeleted, Status, isConfirmed);

create index lat_lng
    on customers (LatitudePoint, LongitudePoint);
```

CalendarItems DDL:

```
create table calendaritems
(
    id             int auto_increment
        primary key,
    TimeStamp      timestamp  default current_timestamp() not null on update current_timestamp(),
    isDone         tinyint(1)                             null,
    isDeleted      tinyint(1) default 0                   not null,
    subject        varchar(255)                           null,
    startDate      datetime                               not null,
    endDate        datetime                               not null,
    isAllDayEvent  tinyint(1) default 1                   null,
    message        varchar(255)                           null,
    color          varchar(200)                           null,
    rMessage       varchar(255)                           null,
    rTime          datetime                               null,
    rLocationLat   decimal(18, 12)                        null,
    rLocationLong  decimal(18, 12)                        null,
    idAgent        int                                    not null,
    idCustomer     int                                    null,
    idVisitPath    int                                    null,
    isFinal        tinyint(1)                             null,
    idUserCreator  int                                    not null,
    idAgentsRegion int                                    null,
    type           int(5)     default 1                   not null,
    systemFill     tinyint(1) default 0                   not null,
    createDate     datetime                               null,
    reqUp          tinyint(1) default 0                   not null,
    dependOn       int                                    null,
    idPlan         int                                    null comment 'to keep track of customer types of a region inside a plan',
    idPlanTour     int                                    null,
    startTime      time                                   null,
    endTime        time                                   null,
    constraint calendaritems_ibfk_agents
        foreign key (idAgent) references agents (idAgents),
    constraint calendaritems_ibfk_agents2
        foreign key (idUserCreator) references agents (idAgents),
    constraint calendaritems_ibfk_customers
        foreign key (idCustomer) references customers (idCustomer)
            on delete set null
)
    charset = utf8;

create index `Index 10`
    on calendaritems (isDeleted, idAgent, startDate, idCustomer);

create index `Index 14`
    on calendaritems (isDeleted, idAgent, idAgentsRegion, idPlan, startDate, endDate);

create index `Index 7`
    on calendaritems (startDate);

create index `Index 8`
    on calendaritems (isDeleted, idAgent, startDate, idVisitPath);

create index `Index 9`
    on calendaritems (isDeleted, idAgent, startDate, idAgentsRegion);

create index createDate
    on calendaritems (createDate);

create index idAgent
    on calendaritems (idAgent);

create index idAgentsRegion
    on calendaritems (idAgentsRegion);

create index idCustomer
    on calendaritems (idCustomer);

create index idUserCreator
    on calendaritems (idUserCreator);

create index idVisitPath
    on calendaritems (idVisitPath);

create index reqUp
    on calendaritems (reqUp);

create index `systemFill-startDate-idAgent-idPlan`
    on calendaritems (systemFill, startDate, idAgent, idPlan);
```

CustomersRegion DDL:

```
create table customersregion
(
    idCustomer int                                      not null,
    idRegion   int                                      not null,
    idCompany  int          default 0                   null,
    isDeleted  tinyint(1)   default 0                   null,
    TimeStamp  timestamp    default current_timestamp() null on update current_timestamp(),
    ERPCode    varchar(255) default ''                  null,
    createDate datetime                                 null,
    primary key (idCustomer, idRegion),
    constraint customersregion_ibfk_1
        foreign key (idCustomer) references customers (idCustomer)
            on update cascade on delete cascade,
    constraint customersregion_ibfk_2
        foreign key (idRegion) references region (idRegion)
            on update cascade on delete cascade
)
    charset = utf8;

create index idRegion
    on customersregion (idRegion);

create index isdeleted_idregion_idcustomer
    on customersregion (isDeleted, idRegion, idCustomer);
```

Comment: check your query execution plan

Comment: Please include the exact index definitions.

Comment: Add full table's DDLs.

Comment: some of your date conditions seem odd; can you explain in English what they are supposed to do?

Comment: is there some practical maximum difference between startDate and endDate?

Comment: best way to show the table DDL is the text output of `show create table yourtablename`

Comment: No, is not practical maximum difference between startDate and endDate. @ysth

Comment: Simple explanation:
We need events in a specific historical period

Comment: Unfortunately the EXPLAIN plan is somewhat useless without knowing SHOW CREATE TABLE output for all tables involved ...

Comment: All table DDL are in question @HartmutHolzgraefe

Answer (score 0):

Unless you can assume startDate is no more than e.g. 30 days before endDate, there is no practical way to index for this query to avoid having to check all rows.  You can try a composite index on (startDate,endDate) and that may help some.

You can try doing a union with some of your where conditions using a start date index and some using an end date index, but if you really are expecting half a million of your 3.8 million rows to get selected, it may not help at all.

Answer (score 0):

The EXPLAIN plan shows that the first step taken is to scan the calendaritems table ("rbase"), scanning a total of estimated 1.6 million rows.

There is an index being used, but it's not really fitting as it has too many extra columns not really used. A better index would be one consisting of (isDeleted, startDate, endDate, idAgentsRegion), in that order, the first three columns of that would be perfect for the first three OR parts of the WHERE condition, but unfortunately not for the last one.

The idAgentsRegion column is not needed for the WHERE or JOIN conditions at all, by adding it you make the index a "covering" one though, so that all data needed can be retrieved from the index alone, without extra lookup steps needed for actual table rows.

What I would do in this case would be to have two indexes, one on (isDeleted, startDate, endDate, idAgentsRegion) and one on just (isDeleted, startDate, endDate, idAgentsRegion), and then split the query into two separate ones combined by UNION:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `cr`.`idCustomer`, `rbase`.`id`
FROM `customers` `t`
    JOIN `customersregion` `cr` ON t.idCustomer = cr.idCustomer and cr.isDeleted = 0
    JOIN `calendaritems` `rbase` ON rbase.idAgentsRegion = cr.idRegion and rbase.isDeleted = 0
where (
    (rbase.startDate <= '2020-07-06 00:00:00' and rbase.endDate   >= '2020-07-06 00:00:00') or
    (rbase.startDate <= '2020-07-28 00:00:00' and rbase.endDate   >= '2020-07-28 00:00:00') or
    (rbase.startDate >= '2020-07-06 00:00:00' and rbase.startDate <= '2020-07-28 23:59:59') 
)
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT `cr`.`idCustomer`, `rbase`.`id`
FROM `customers` `t`
    JOIN `customersregion` `cr` ON t.idCustomer = cr.idCustomer and cr.isDeleted = 0
    JOIN `calendaritems` `rbase` ON rbase.idAgentsRegion = cr.idRegion and rbase.isDeleted = 0
where (rbase.endDate   >= '2020-07-06 00:00:00' and rbase.endDate   <= '2020-07-28 23:59:59')
```

For the first part the first index is perfect, for the 2nd part the 2nd index is perfect, leading to much smaller index range scans, and in the end the results just need to be combined and duplicates removed.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is a foreign key relation from customersreqion to customers, so you don't need the customers table in your query. You don't select anything from it and the foreign key relation already ensures that you won't select any customerid's that are not in the customers table. This doesn't reduce your 100 seconds significantly, but every bit helps.

To get full gain of indexes, you will need two extra indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX firstindextoadd ON calendaritems(idAgentsRegion, isDeleted, startDate, endDate);
CREATE INDEX secondindextoadd ON calendaritems(idAgentsRegion, isDeleted, endDate);
```

The first index will be used for your first 3 conditions:

```
(rbase.startDate <= '2020-07-06 00:00:00' and rbase.endDate   >= '2020-07-06 00:00:00') or
(rbase.startDate <= '2020-07-28 00:00:00' and rbase.endDate   >= '2020-07-28 00:00:00') or
(rbase.startDate >= '2020-07-06 00:00:00' and rbase.startDate <= '2020-07-28 23:59:59')
```

The second will be your for the forth condition:

```
 (rbase.endDate   >= '2020-07-06 00:00:00' and rbase.endDate   <= '2020-07-28 23:59:59')
```

It depends on the number of deleted records if you should include the isDeleted, but I added them 'just in case'.

It didn't test it on a huge dataset, so you need to tell me if this worked for you.

In addtion you can simplify your conditions to:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `cr`.`idCustomer`, `rbase`.`id`
FROM `customersregion` `cr` ON t.idCustomer = cr.idCustomer and cr.isDeleted = 0
    JOIN `calendaritems` `rbase` ON rbase.idAgentsRegion = cr.idRegion and rbase.isDeleted = 0
where 
    rbase.startDate <= '2020-07-06 00:00:00' and rbase.endDate >= '2020-07-28 00:00:00' OR
    rbase.startDate BETWEEN '2020-07-06 00:00:00' and '2020-07-28 00:00:00' OR
    rbase.endDate BETWEEN '2020-07-06 00:00:00' and '2020-07-28 00:00:00'
```

Comment: MySQL rarely uses two indexes in a single `SELECT`.

Comment: @RickJames I just checked the planner implementation on [GitHub](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/8.0/sql/sql_planner.cc) and there is a chance that only the first index will be used, in that case the query needs to be split-up. But you need to play with the query and the indexes to see what really happens.

Comment: It is likely to pick the index with `startDate` earlier when there are fewer rows in the table satisfying it than the other table.  Try the query again, but shifting both dates back a few months or years.

Comment: As for that GitHub, is there anything other than these six words "Create plan for a single select" to explain how to run it or which versions it works against or why to use it instead of `EXPLAIN`?

Answer (score 0):

```
rbase:  INDEX(isDeleted, startDate, endDate, idAgentsRegion, id)
rbase:  INDEX(isDeleted, endDate, startDate, idAgentsRegion, id)
```

Those have these qualities:

- First two columns are useful in ON and WHERE.
- Optimizer will pick between them based on whether `startDate` or `endDate` is more selective.
- Covering

That assumes that the Optimizer will start with `rbase`.  If, instead, it starts with `cr`, then have both of these for the Optimizer to choose between:

```
rbase:  INDEX(idAgentsRegion, isDeleted, startDate, endDate, id)
rbase:  INDEX(idAgentsRegion, isDeleted, endDate, startDate, id)
```

`cr` is the only other table that the Optimizer might start with.  (There is a `WHERE` clause to filter by.)

```
cr:  INDEX(isDeleted, idRegion,  -- first, (in either order)
           idCustomer)           -- last
```

Assuming that start <= end, the range test can probably be simplified to only this:

```
WHERE rbase.startDate  < '2020-07-28'
  AND rbase.endDate   >= '2020-07-06'
```

(I don't recognize the funnybusiness with '2020-07-28' versus '2020-07-28 23:59:59'.)

I recommend using "< midnight" and ">= midnight" consistently.  A plain date is equivalent to midnight for that morning.  Another way to specify `'2020-07-28'` is `'2020-07-06' + INTERVAL 22 DAY`.  The latter is convenient when you know the span (22 days) and don't want to fuss with leap days, etc.

It is "proper" for the `ON` to specify how the tables are 'related', and the `WHERE` to be used for filtering.  That is, the `isDeleted` tests belong in the `WHERE` clause.  (The execution is unaffected for `JOIN`, but important for `LEFT JOIN`.)

The `Last...Id...` and `Last...Name` columns seem to be redundant?  Somewhere else there is a mapping from `id` to `name`?

`Rates` and `Colors` -- Those seem like things that are not worth normalizing?  If you ever need to search on either, undoing this normalization will help performance, possibly a lot.

This combo seems 'wrong'; is there a reason for it:

```
startDate  DATETIME
startTime  TIME
```

When you have both of these,

```
INDEX(a)     -- drop
INDEX(a,b)   -- keep (it takes care of the other case)
```

`LatitudePoint decimal(18, 12)` takes 9 bytes; gross overkill.  Suggested alternatives:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/latlng#representation_choices